# JavaFX: Bind row height to amount of rows in a TableView?

Tags: javafx, tableview

I'm looking for a way to bind the row height (or cellSize) to the amount of rows in my TableView. 
The height of the row would be equal to the height of the table divided by the amount of rows.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by adding the following method in my class that extends TableView:

```
private void fixCellSize(){
        int amountOfRows = getItems().size();
        double headerHeight = lookup(".column-header-background").getBoundsInLocal().getHeight();
        setFixedCellSize((getHeight()-headerHeight)/amountOfRows);
    }
```

In my constructor I added:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> fixCellSize());
```

Comment: Unrelated but can't be repeated often enough: _Dont extend controls_! Instead, configure them as needed.

Comment: Why? If you want to add extra methods, what would be the best way to do that without extending controls?

Comment: think _functionality_ not method - that's basic OO principles nothing special to fx..

Comment: Okay, what is the best way to add functionality to controls without extending them?

Comment: if you add functionality (== enhanced/additional services that can be and is intended to be used by many applications) extending is fine. If you just add a convenience method for the sake of your single application, configuration is the way to go.  Your method being private looks more like the latter for me, though .. boundaries can be fuzzy :))